# Analytic functions and means of window clause for calculating sum

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I'm using Oracle and SQL Developer. I have downloaded HR schema and need to do some queries with it. Now I'm working with table Employees. As a user, I need the sum of salary of 3 employees with highest salary in each department. I have done query for defining 3 employees with highest salary in each department:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            employee_id,
            first_name
            || ' '
            || last_name,
            department_id,
            salary,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(PARTITION BY department_id
                 ORDER BY
                     salary DESC  
                 --ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING     
            ) result
        FROM
            employees
    )
WHERE
    result <= 3;
```

I need to use means of window clause. I have done something like this:

```
SELECT
    department_id,
    SUM(salary)
    OVER (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY salary       
    ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) total_sal
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            employee_id,
            first_name
            || ' '
            || last_name,
            department_id,
            salary,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(PARTITION BY department_id
                 ORDER BY
                     salary DESC  
                 --ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING     
            ) result
        FROM
            employees
    )
WHERE
    result <= 3;
```

Here is the result:

[image: Intermediate result]

It has the necessary sum for 3 people in department and other unnnecessary results for 2 and so on. I need such result:

[image: Final result]

How can I modify my query to receive appropriate result (**I need to use a window clause and analytic fuctions**)?

Comment: I suggest you try to use nested SELECT with window clause and then outer SELECT with MAX() to receive what do you need like in second picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want aggregation rather than windowing in the outer query:

```
SELECT
    department_id,
    SUM(salary) total_sal
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            employee_id,
            first_name
            || ' '
            || last_name,
            department_id,
            salary,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER(PARTITION BY department_id
                 ORDER BY
                     salary DESC  
                 --ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING     
            ) result
        FROM
            employees
    ) e
WHERE
    result <= 3
GROUP BY department_id
```

---

I we were to do the same task with window functions only, then, starting from the existing query, we can either add another level of nesting of some sort, or use `WITH TIES`. Both pursue the same effect, which is to limit the results to one row per group.

The latter would look like:

```
SELECT 
    department_id,
    SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY department_id) total_sal
FROM (
        SELECT e.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY salary DESC) result
        FROM employees e
) e
WHERE result <= 3
ORDER BY result FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

While the former would phrase as:

```
SELECT department_id, total_sal
FROM (
    SELECT e.*,
        SUM(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY department_id) total_sal
    FROM (
        SELECT e.*, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY salary DESC) result
        FROM employees e
    ) e
    WHERE result <= 3
) e
where result = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for advice! I have been using the same, but I need exactly window clause.

Comment: Can you suggest solution exactly with means of window clause, please?

Comment: @Andy: you want one row per department, which is aggregation in essence. Why do you specifically want to use window functions for that task (knowing that you are already using them to identify the top 3 employees per department, which is a good thing)?

Comment: Yeah, I see that aggregation is better, but the task is to use exactly a window clause. I need actually to compare both results and write some conclusion.

Comment: Do you have any ideas or maybe suggestions how to do this?

Comment: @GMB: I see that Andy have asked about some analytic functions, not aggregate and that he needs a windowing clause which is used with `ORDER BY`. I consider that aggregate functions is better in such cases, but I see that the task is exactly opposite. Your answer is not optimal for that question.

Comment: @Andy: I edited my answer with window-function based suggestions.

Comment: @Vorrven: I agree that Andy made a clear statement on using windowing functions, which I did not pay enough attention to. I updated the answer!

Comment: @Vorrven While use of analytic functions may be a requirement, it is suboptimal in this particular case, especially for supportability (including future you trying to guess the original intent of this complication). If this is an assignment question, then... It's not a good showcase. To be precise, this doesn't require [`windowing_clause`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/windowing_clause.html) because top N doesn't require any offset relative to the *current* row. Default window specifications are not required also and may be specified by `order by`

Comment: @astentx yes, your remark is quite helpful, but still I see that person asks directly in question about specific solution. Of course, there are a lot of means to find good solution for this task and optimize it or maybe simplify it. I just point attention on persons' question in which he or she needs help.